# Can "quintuple," "sextuple," etc. be used as determiners?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, determiners

I've seen *treble* and *double* used as determiners. Is it valid to use *quadruple*, *quintuple*, *sextuple*, and the equivalent words for greater numbers in the same way?

For example:

> The outlay on housing was **quintuple** that on education.

Comment: You can, but the higher you go, the less likely you are to be understood. It is better to use four-fold, five-fold, etc.

Comment: Why do you feel that you might not be able to use them as determiners?

Comment: Because I din't find 'sextuple' in Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary'- 8th edition.

Answer (score 1):

For your example, usually "five times" would be used in place of "quintuple" though the meanings are the same

> The outlay on housing was *five times* that on education.

It could be because most people may not be familiar with Latin and "x times" is easier to understand once one is past "double", "twice", or "triple".

> 1 single
>   2 double
>   3 triple/treble
>   4 quadruple
>   5 quintuple pentadruple
>   6 sextuple hexatruple
>   7 septuple
>   8 octuple
>   9 nonuple
>   10 decuple
>   11 undecuple hendecuple
>   12 duodecuple
>   13 tredecuple
>   100 centuple
>
> - from [here](https://www.quora.com/If-1-Single-2-Double-3-Triple-4-Quadruple-what-are-5-6-7-8-etc-called)